# Loading a MAT file without creating an intermediate variable

Tags: matlab, file-io, dataset, structure, mat-file

I am trying to load a MAT file and getting a dataset as an output. If I run

```
a = load('foo.mat');
```

**a** is a structure and not a dataset. In order to get a dataset I need to run the following code

```
load('foo.mat');
a = foo;
```

Though, in this way in my workspace I have two identical datasets, specifically **a** and **foo**.

Is there a way to just write a line of code and import the MAT file and get a single dataset rather than two?

Comment: In the secong option, If you dont assign `a=foo`, you have one dataset called `foo`

Comment: Yes, do `load('foo.mat');` and you will only have `foo`. If you want it to be called `a`, then add `clear foo`  in the end to your second snippet

Comment: @Adiel yes I forgot to add that I did not want the variable to be called 'foo' (in my actual case the name is very long and relatively unusable).

Comment: Note that MATLAB doesn’t copy the data when you do `a=foo`. As long as you don’t modify one of these variables, you will have the data in memory only once.

Comment: You can use `a = load('foo.mat'); a = a.foo;`. It is chip and actually no copy is made.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bad idea to do `load` w/o assigning it to a variable, because this makes it difficult to track changes to your workspace.

I would generally do,

```
a = struct2array(load('foo.mat'));
```

But this has some limitations (e.g. it only works if `foo.mat` contains a single variable).

Comment: _it only works if `foo.mat` contains a single variable_ You can use `a = struct2array(load('foo.mat', 'foo'));`

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, thanks for the clarification. I meant that the command _as it is written_ is good for a single variable.

Answer (score 4):

Create a separate function to load your data.

```
function[foo] = loader()
load('foo.mat');
end
```

Then call it as:

```
a = loader();
```

Because the function has a closed scope, you can load the variables with the names they have in the mat file. When the function returns, you assign the value to whatever name you want.

Comment: This is definitely better than loading directly into the active workspace, however the issue with a function like this is that `foo` is technically not being defined in the scope of the function, which issues a warning IIRC. I would suggest adding "invalid" default values (e.g. `NaN`) for all expected outputs, or testing with `exist` that all desired variables were actually created.

Comment: @Dev-iL Adding `%#ok` will suppress the warning on the text editor. Depending on your coding standards, that might be good enough. (I do admit this is kinda of a YOLO suggestion on my part).